# TEXT compression in python

Tags: python, text-compression

I have this text :

2,3,5,1,13,7,17,11,89,1,233,29,61,47,1597,19,37,41,421,199,28657,23,3001,521,53,281,514229,31,557,2207,19801,3571,141961,107,73,9349,135721,2161,2789,211,433494437,43,109441,139,2971215073,1103,97,101,6376021,90481,953,5779,661,14503,797,59,353,2521,4513,3010349,35239681,1087,14736206161,9901,269,67,137,71,6673,103681,9375829,54018521,230686501,29134601,988681,79,157,1601,2269,370248451,99194853094755497,83,9521,6709,173,263,1069,181,741469,4969,4531100550901,6643838879,761,769,193,599786069,197,401,743519377,919,519121,103,8288823481,119218851371,1247833,11128427,827728777,331,1459000305513721,10745088481,677,229,1381,347,29717,709,159512939815855788121,

This are numbers generated from my generator program,**now the problem has a source code limit so I can't use the above texts in my solution** so I want to compress this and put it into a data-structure in python so that I can print them by indexing like:

```
F = [`compressed data`]
```

and `F[0]` would give `2 F[5]` would give `7` like this ... Please suggest me a suitable compression technique.

PS: I am a very newbie to python so please explain your method.

Comment: I don't see any compression here.  Are you sure that's the word you mean?

Comment: compression? that doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: What's the size of your number list? How fast do you need to get number for an index? Does this number list has any boundaries, properties, characteristics or any other information about number sequence? You say that you have source code limit. What is it? Do you have any memory limit? There are various compressing algorithms and the right choice depends on your restrictions and available information.

Comment: Given a value of N I have output the value of F[N] now the initialization of F[] should be such that F = [ 2,3,5,1,13,7,17,11,89,1,233,...] but instead of numbers I have use the compressed value so that the overall source code limit suffices.

Comment: @Tretwick Marian: Can you elaborate more what you mean by `the problem has a source code limit` and `can't use the above texts in my solution`. Are you participating to some kind of coding competition? Btw have you considered to just save the 'text' to a file and read it later when needed to a list?

Comment: @Tretwick. You need to explain *what you are trying to do* and let us tell you *how to do it*. You're trying to do something but you are choosing a very bad way to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure you can do this:

```
import base64
import zlib
compressed = 'eJwdktkNgDAMQxfqR+5j/8V4QUJQUttx3Nrzl0+f+uunPPpm+Tf3Z/tKX1DM5bXP+wUFA777bCob4HMRfUk14QwfDYPrrA5gcuQB49lQQxdZpdr+1oN2bEA3pW5Nf8NGOFsR19NBszyX7G2raQpkVUEBdbTLuwSRlcDCYiW7GeBaRYJrgImrM3lmI/WsIxFXNd+aszXoRXuZ1PnZRdwKJeqYYYKq6y1++PXOYdgM0TlZcymCOdKqR7HYmYPiRslDr2Sn6C0Wgw+a6MakM2VnBk6HwU6uWqDRz+p6wtKTCg2WsfdKJwfJlHNaFT4+Q7PGfR9hyWK3p3464nhFwpOd7kdvjmz1jpWcxmbG/FJUXdMZgrpzs+jxC11twrBo3TaNgvsf8oqIYwT4r9XkPnNC1XcP7qD5cW7UHSJZ3my5qba+ozncl5kz8gGEEYOQ'
data = zlib.decompress(base64.b64decode(compressed))
```

Note that this is only 139 characters shorter.
But it works:

```
>>> data
'2,3,5,1,13,7,17,11,89,1,233,29,61,47,1597,19,37,41,421,199,28657,23,3001,521,53,281,514229,31,557,2207,19801,3571,141961,107,73,9349,135721,2161,2789,211,433494437,43,109441,139,2971215073,1103,97,101,6376021,90481,953,5779,661,14503,797,59,353,2521,4513,3010349,35239681,1087,14736206161,9901,269,67,137,71,6673,103681,9375829,54018521,230686501,29134601,988681,79,157,1601,2269,370248451,99194853094755497,83,9521,6709,173,263,1069,181,741469,4969,4531100550901,6643838879,761,769,193,599786069,197,401,743519377,919,519121,103,8288823481,119218851371,1247833,11128427,827728777,331,1459000305513721,10745088481,677,229,1381,347,29717,709,159512939815855788121,'
```

If your code limit really is so short, maybe you are supposed to calculate this data or something? What is it?

Comment: And how did you get the compressed value programatically ? :)

Comment: I did the same thing, but in reverse.

Comment: Okay let me try to rephrase :) I want to know how you obtain the compressed value in that format ? since something like this http://ideone.com/EDftR is not giving me that value.

Comment: Yeah, I said *reverse*. You obviously have to reverse the order of the actions, ie `base64.b64encode(zlib.compress(s))`

Comment: I have up-voted this one :) Now I understand both of the solutions :)

Comment: When I run the reverse code where `s` is a `str`, the interpreter says: `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 5):

[zlib](http://docs.python.org/library/zlib.html) would get the job done, if you indeed want compression. If you don't want compression, then I'm afraid that my mind-reading skills are on the wane.

Comment: gzip + base64 may indeed have smaller size than the source text. I just tried to do that with the digits presented, and  it compressed the text from 663 to 475 bytes. Not stellar, though.

Comment: I guess this is what I am looking for but I am new to pyth so could please explain the compression and decompression technique ?

Comment: @Tretwick Compressing makes it take up less space. zlib is lossless compression so no information is lost. Decompression is the inverse operation. Did you read the link I included in my answer?

Comment: Yes I did,say I want to compress a text 'My name is Tretwick' hence I write zlib.compress('My name is Tretwick') but then I have to print it and then to get the compressed data back to get the original I have to use zlib.decompress() but when I print it it give me some different things which is not working if I copy paste into the decompress module. I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Tretwick I guess you're doing it wrong somehow, but I don't know off the top of my head. The simple compress/decompress cycle you propose works fine for me.

Comment: Please tell me how would you do ? I give you a text you have to compress it and then give me the text so that I can use the decompress on it ?:)

Comment: @Tretwick Try `zlib.decompress(zlib.compress('My name is Tretwick'))`

Comment: This is not I want I have told you that that I can't use the actual text in the decompresser program.

Comment: @Tretwick I don't understand anything you have said. You need to make yourself more clear.

Comment: @Tretwick What happened to the other answers that were here before. Did you scare them away?

Comment: That was not something that I was looking for :) I am not here to scare anyone

Answer (score 2):

On Python 2.4-2.7, pypy, jython:

```
>>> enc = sdata.encode('zlib').encode('base64')
>>> print enc
eJwdktkNgDAMQxfqR+5j/8V4QUJQUttx3Nrzl0+f+uunPPpm+Tf3Z/tKX1DM5bXP+wUFA777bCob
4HMRfUk14QwfDYPrrA5gcuQB49lQQxdZpdr+1oN2bEA3pW5Nf8NGOFsR19NBszyX7G2raQpkVUEB
dbTLuwSRlcDCYiW7GeBaRYJrgImrM3lmI/WsIxFXNd+aszXoRXuZ1PnZRdwKJeqYYYKq6y1++PXO
YdgM0TlZcymCOdKqR7HYmYPiRslDr2Sn6C0Wgw+a6MakM2VnBk6HwU6uWqDRz+p6wtKTCg2WsfdK
JwfJlHNaFT4+Q7PGfR9hyWK3p3464nhFwpOd7kdvjmz1jpWcxmbG/FJUXdMZgrpzs+jxC11twrBo
3TaNgvsf8oqIYwT4r9XkPnNC1XcP7qD5cW7UHSJZ3my5qba+ozncl5kz8gGEEYOQ
>>> print enc.decode('base64').decode('zlib')[:79]
2,3,5,1,13,7,17,11,89,1,233,29,61,47,1597,19,37,41,421,199,28657,23,3001,521,53
>>> sdata == enc.decode('base64').decode('zlib')
True
>>> F = [int(s) for s in sdata.split(',') if s.strip()]
>>> F[0], F[5]
(2, 7)
```